# How do I convert the bytes1 to int in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I would like to ask that, how could I convert `bytes1` to `int`.

The following is the snippet of my code:

```cpp
int256[] public C;
function setVal(string memory C_) public returns(int[] memory ret1) {
    bytes memory b = bytes(C_);
    for (uint i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        if (b[i] >= 0x30 && b[i] <= 0x39) {
            C.push(int256(int8(b[i]) - 48));
        }
    }
    return C;
}
```

And it will show an Error message:

> TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes1" to "int8"

Comment: Maybe this could help: [How to convert bytes to uint in Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/51229/how-to-convert-bytes-to-uint-in-solidity)?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Thanks for your reply. But it couldn't work after alter the type "uint" to "int".

Answer (score 2):

`bytes1` has size of 8 bits (possible values `0x00` to `0xff`), which you can implicitly convert to `uint8` (unsigned integer of size 8 bits) but not to `int8` (signed integer of size 8 bits including the plus/minus sign) because the highest values would not fit into `int8`.

For example: If the value of `bytes1` is `0xff`, that's represented as decimal 255. The maximal value of `uint8` is 255 (and minimal is 0), while the maximal value of `int8` is 127 (and minimal is -127). So the value 255 would not fit into `int8` - and that's why the compiler doesn't allow you to just convert any `bytes1` into `int8`.

Similarly, you can implicitly convert `uint8` into `uint256` - but cannot implicitly convert it to `int256` because the highest values of `uint256` would not fit into `int256`.

Finally, since you're now trying to push `uint256` type into `C` variable, you need to change its type as well as the type returned from the function to `uint256`.

```
uint256[] public C;
function setVal(string memory C_) public returns(uint[] memory ret1) {
    bytes memory b = bytes(C_);
    for (uint i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        if (b[i] >= 0x30 && b[i] <= 0x39) {
            C.push(uint256(uint8(b[i]) - 48));
        }
    }
    return C;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I need the negative number  to next step in my project.